# Recursive object not passed over WCF

Tags: wcf

I will explain my class design

```
public class A
{
   public Ilist<B> Something { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
   public A ParentA { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am trying to pass A over WCF and it just throws an exception. Is there some attribute I have to set to get this to work or is it not at all possible in WCF

Comment: You need to accept some more answers. You will get more responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try decorating class A with:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
```

And class B with only:

```
[DataContract]
```

That will tell WCF that these are types you're going to be using in your service, and `IsReference` will take care of the circular reference problem as well as cutting down on the size of your message.  You might also try playing around with putting `IsReference` on B and not on A - I don't recall exactly how it behaves off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [DataContracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx)

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(B))]
class A
{
   public Ilist<B> Something { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
class B
{
   public A ParentA { get; set; }
}
```