# can I reference DataContract as DataMember to itself

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a DataContract to be used in a Service Contract, e.g.

```
[DataContract]
public class Task
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Name;
    [DataMember]
    public string Type;
    [DataMember]
    public string Description;
    [DataMember]
    public SubTask[] SubTasks;
}

[DataContract]
public class SubTask
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Name;
    [DataMember]
    public string Type;
    [DataMember]
    public string Description;
    [DataMember]
    public SubTask[] SubTasks;
}
```

**Question**

A subtask can have +10 subtasks, now can I reference DataContract as DataMember to itself like in above example?

```
Task 1
   SubTask 1
       SubSubTask 1
       SubSubTask 2
          SubSubSubTask 1
   SubTask 2
```

Comment: Try it and see. Worth pointing out your SubTask class doesn't actually have any use. Why don't you just have an array of `Task` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use recursive DataContract references in WCF.

You may need to add “IsReference = true” to the DataContract attribute, in order for the DataContractSerializer to properly handle the recursive nature.

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
```

The following links discuss DataContracts with recursive members:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh241056(v=vs.100).aspx
- http://stefanoricciardi.com/2009/10/22/making-wcf-serializer-work-with-circular-references/
- [Recursive object not passed over WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001189/recursive-object-not-passed-over-wcf)